# Pandas read into a single column

Tags: pandas, txt

I am reading from a .txt file into a dataframe using pandas read_csv(). The data is in this form in the txt file (this is a sample):

```
abcd,efgh,ijklm
qwerty,uoipqwrt
mznxlakspqowieu
```

As you can see there are different number of commas in each line. But ultimately I want to put each line of the text file in a single column. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What should the 3rd line look like. Can you share expected results. Also what have you tried so far

Comment: @JoeFerndz Didnt understand your question. The sample I have put is how my txt file looks like. I want each line of the txt file to be one column. But as there are some commas in the random lines in the txt file so there is an issue reading into a data frame